# Passcode-enabled BLE pairing for iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any option built within CoreBluetooth that allows for LESC and passkey-enabled pairing for iOS? From the documentation, I only see a general non-passkey pairing command.

If not, are there any 3rd party libraries that enable this to be possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question ?

Answer (score 3):

LESC Pairing using passkey is the default and will be used unless the peripheral doesn't support it. CoreBluetooth does not have any pairing API. Everything goes through the OS.